# How can I publish all the videos I uploaded to YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I uploaded many videos on YouTube:

[image]

How can I publish them all at once?

I can only find a "Publish all" button on the upload page, but I might close the upload page forgetting to click on it, and it fails to work when the upload page has been open a while ago:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/Niedzwiedzw/youtube-publish-drafts I wrote a little script for that, nothing too fancy just some clicking automated with javascript

Comment: Thank you so much for the js, Mr. Niedzwiedzwo. It works like a charm.

Comment: Still works November 2023

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me a great deal of time. February 2024. Still works !! :)

Answer (score -2):

Create a playlist with your videos, then look here -> https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57793?hl=en